# agregar seguridad a un web services

Tags: vb.net, web

Hola estoy agregando seguridad a un web services soapheader: lo primero he agregado en el webconfig estas lineas:

```
<AppSettings>
<add key="user" value="test"/>
<add key="pass" value="test2020"/>
```

en codigo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al compilar me dá este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me puede ayudar, donde está el error?, muchas gracias

Comment: textoooooo el codigo y error como textooooooo

Answer (score 0):

Hola Ya he podido solucionarlo, en lugar de poner las credenciales en el webconfig (solo para pruebas), lo he puesto desde donde deseo consumirlo.

gracias!